# Woocommerce use product tags to hide menu items using wp_nav_menu_objects filter

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, menu, woocommerce

I am using a wordpress registered menu to display an unordered list of product tags on my product archives page.

I would like to maintain the hierarchy of an unordered list if possible, however, I would like to grey out the list items that have no products associated with them so users are not led to a page with no products.

the unordered list looks like this after wordpress does its thing, so each anchor has a title that is equal to the tag name:

```
<ul id="menu-themes" class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href='#' title='fantasy'>Fantasy</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='#' title='science'>Science</a>
        <ul class='sub-menu'>
            <li>
                <a href='#' title='space'>Space</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>        
</ul>
```

I used a filter to change the href of each anchor to be appropriate. This is the filter I used in order to change this specific menu's anchor links:

```
function change_menu( $items, $args ){
    if( $args->theme_location == "themes" ){

        foreach($items as $item){
            global $wp;
            $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));

            $item->url = $current_url . '/?product_tag=' . $item->title;


        }

    }

  return $items;

}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'change_menu', 10, 2);
```

I have gotten a list of all the relevant tags to print out by using:

```
function woocommerce_product_loop_tags() {
    global $post, $product;



    echo $product->get_tags();
}
```

Now let's say for example, this above function only echo's space. Is there a way to filter the menu further to hide all the menu items that do not equal space?

I'm thinking it would be something like this:

```
function filter_menu_by_tags($items, $args){
    //set scope of $product variable
    global $product;
    //this if statement makes sure only the themes menu is affected.
    if( $args->theme_location == "themes"){
        //loop through each menu item
        foreach($items as $item){
            if($item->title does not match any of the tags in $product->get_tags()){
                //then add a special class to the list item or anchor tag
            }
            else{
                 //do nothing and let it print out normally.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$product->get_tags()` returns an array of tags. You can use PHP `in_array()` function to check if your title is on the list:

```
function filter_menu_by_tags($items, $args){
    //set scope of $product variable
    global $product;
    //this if statement makes sure only the themes menu is affected.
    if( $args->theme_location == "themes"){
        //loop through each menu item
        foreach($items as $item){
            if( !in_array($item->title, $product->get_tags()) ){
                // Title is not in_array Tags
                //then add a special class to the list item or anchor tag
            }
            else{
                 // Title is in_array Tags
                 //do nothing and let it print out normally.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction :D thank you. `$product->get_tags()` does not return an array, though so the `!in_array()` throws an error because It returns a string. Do you know how to make it into an array? I believe `!in_array()` should be the right answer :)

Comment: I'm looking at woocommerce's reference (can't say what version), it says usage is: `$array = WC_Product::get_tags( $sep, $before, $after );` it should return an array

Comment: Yeah, I saw that as well, however, I'm getting this error: Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in.....(directory location)

Comment: if you `print_r( $product->get_tags() );` what's the output?

Comment: `decal, fairies, fairy, fantasy, mythology, nymph, sprite, sticker, vinyl` These are surrounded by anchor tags. maybe it needs to be sanitized? Also I did `var_dump( $product->get_tags() );` and I got this output `string(785) "decal, fairies, fairy, fantasy, mythology, nymph, sprite, sticker, vinyl" `

Comment: well this is very brutal: you can explode your string to an array before the foreach `$arr_tags = explode( ", ", $product->getTags() );`  and then check if it is in array `if( !in_array($item->title, $arr_tags) ){ ...... }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92782/discussion-between-chris-haugen-and-graficode-studio).

Comment: Ok, I know what's wrong, I just don't know how to tackle it. `$arr_tags` is in an array and the strings are surrounded by `<a></a>` tags so it's comparing  the string `fantasy` to this `<a>fantasy</a>` which isn't working. How do you remove the anchor tags from the array?